# Parse Server Incompatible pointer error after updating to Xcode 12 beta 6

Tags: swift, xcode, parse-server

So it used to work just fine but after updating both MacOS and Xcode to latest betas the Parse server cocoa pod no longer works. It throws this error:

[image]

I honestly have no idea what is going on here. Any idea why that might happen?
Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-iOS-OSX/issues/1541

Comment: Great, thanks for pointing to this. Seems best way out of it is to fix manually for the time being and wait for new release